# cursor loader for each content provider uri

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm reading about cursor loaders, and I want to use them to observe changes on my sqlite db and for future use with GCM. I want to ask a simple question, should I make a cursor loader for each URI that I use in my Content provider, or there is a way to make only one general loader that will observe and change on any URI and update the corresponding activity?

To make my question specific to my case, I'll explain what i want to do. I'm making a social media app, so I have a list of feeds list view of which each list item will contain another list view that represents the comments. so I think I'll have two cursor adapters and two loaders, is that right?

Comment: what do you mean by "make a cursor loader for each UR"?

Comment: as i saw on a tutorial, it says that in return new CursorLoader(URI, ...), you return they URI of the data of interest .. so does that mean I have to create loaders for each URI or I misunderstood the concept?

Comment: you dont "make" a cursor loader, its done by calling new `CursorLoader(Uri, ...)` and you call this ctor only for Uri you are interested in

Comment: I've edited my question, please tell me if I'm designing it right or I still need to think and read more about android database concepts?

Comment: you cannot have ListView inside another ListView, what you can use is an ExpandableListView or 2 Activities (master/detail) with 2 separate ListViews